# Scripting with Variables not working?

Tags: bash, shell, variables, unix, scripting

I am trying to learn some unix and I am trying to script some basic variables, any idea why this won't work when I sh math?

```
> vi math 
A=5
B=10
let C=A+B
let D=B-A
let E=A*B
let F=A/B
echo $A $B $C $D $E $F
```

here is what is showing.

```
math: 4: math: let: not found
math: 5: math: let: not found
math: 6: math: let: not found
math: 7: math: let: not found
5 10
```

Comment: What is not working? You should use bash to run it using `bash ./math`

Comment: The modern POSIX-standard way to do math is `C=$((A+B))`. `let` is a relic of a bygone age.

Comment: ...also, "won't work" isn't exactly useful. If you described *exactly* what it does, that would let folks be more helpful.

Comment: Your output is identical to what I see when using `dash`.  Can you show the output of: `bash math` and then `sh math` and then `dash math`?  I expect the output of `sh math` to be identical to that of `dash math`.

Comment: Yeah, it works when I do Bash math... 

> sh math
math: 4: math: let: not found
math: 5: math: let: not found
math: 6: math: let: not found
math: 7: math: let: not found
5 10
> bash math
5 10 15 5 50 0
> dash math
math: 4: math: let: not found
math: 5: math: let: not found
math: 6: math: let: not found
math: 7: math: let: not found
5 10

Comment: So, on your machine, `sh` is not `bash` but `dash`.  Include `#!/bin/bash` as the first line of your script and you should be OK.  Or run explicitly with `bash`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On a system where `/bin/sh` is Bash (Mac OS X 10.9.2 Mavericks), then I get:

```
$ cat math
A=5
B=10
let C=A+B
let D=B-A
let E=A*B
let F=A/B
echo $A $B $C $D $E $F
$ sh math
5 10 15 5 50 0
$ bash math
5 10 15 5 50 0
$ ksh math
5 10 15 5 50 0
$ dash math
math: 3: math: let: not found
math: 4: math: let: not found
math: 5: math: let: not found
math: 6: math: let: not found
5 10
$ hsh math
math: let: not found
math: let: not found
math: let: not found
math: let: not found
5 10
$
```

(`hsh` is the Heirloom Bourne Shell installed as another name.)

That means that both `sh math` and `bash math` do the arithmetic as you intended.  Are you perhaps on a machine with a different shell as `/bin/sh` (perhaps it is `dash` in disguise and you're on [Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh))?

Comment: Doing this #!/bin/sh
A=5
B=10
let C=A+B
let D=B-A
let E=A*B
let F=A/B
echo $A $B $C $D $E $F
but it i still not working.

Comment: Can you provide more details about your environment?  Which O/S and version?  Which version of Bash?  (Use `bash --version` to find out. Does `/bin/sh --version` say the same thing?) When you say "it is not working", what exactly are you seeing as error messages?  Please add these details to the question rather than the comments here.  And in future, please include in particular the exact error messages you are seeing in the question up front; it means we have to make fewer guesses about what you're seeing go wrong.

Comment: GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)editing my question with what appears.